# Gradle : Task dependency tree ignored?

Tags: java, gradle, war

I have a problem with gradle's task dependencies.

I have a version.properties file which must be cleared (on clean task) or filled (on war task) with a version info.

Therefore I set this dependency :

```
clean.dependsOn clearVersionProperties
```

and

```
processResources.dependsOn ([defaultValues,infoEnv])
compileJsps.dependsOn(classes, tomcatJasper, xmlModify)
war.dependsOn(compileJsps, svnRevision, writeVersionProperties)
```

My tasks have been externalized in a commons.gradle and look like this:

```
...

def writeVersionFile(String whatToWrite) {
    File f = new File(project.webAppDirName+'/WEB-INF/version.properties');
    if (f.exists()) { f.delete(); }

    f = new File(project.webAppDirName+'/WEB-INF/version.properties');
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
    os.write(whatToWrite.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}

task clearVersionProperties() {
    println "Clearing version file"
    String whatToWrite = "version=@version@"
    writeVersionFile(whatToWrite)
}

task writeVersionProperties(dependsOn: svnRevision) {
    println "Writing version file"
    String whatToWrite = "version="+project.ext.revision;
    writeVersionFile(whatToWrite)
}
...
```

From my understanding clean will now call clearVersionProperties and war will call writeVersionProperties.

But when I execute a gradle clean, the reactor plan looks like this :

```
C:\devtools\....\branches\merge\Application>gradle -bbuild20.gradle clean -Ptomcat=7 -Ptarget=live

To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: http://gradle.org/
docs/2.0/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
_______________________________________________________________________________

### building LIVE system

_______________________________________________________________________________
Clearing version file
Writing version file
JSP compilation...
TC7 Sources integrated
________________________________________________________
Compiling JSPs against Tomcat 7.0.11
________________________________________________________
:clearVersionProperties UP-TO-DATE
:clean UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 16.803 secs
```

Why are the tasks clearVersionProperties and writeVersionProperties executed, since they are bound to certain build phases? for example the task infoEnv is not executed, but - and this is really a problem - the task writeVersionProperties which only should be executed by the war task.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the meantime I found out why these tasks were fired :

I missed << after the task statement, so changing my two taks to

```
task clearVersionProperties() << {
    println "Clearing version file"
    String whatToWrite = "version=@version@"
    writeVersionFile(whatToWrite)
}

task writeVersionProperties(dependsOn: [svnRevision]) << {
    println "Writing version file"
    String whatToWrite = "version="+project.ext.revision;
    writeVersionFile(whatToWrite)
}

writeVersionProperties.mustRunAfter clearVersionProperties
```

This did the job.... I am not sure, if this is a bug, feature or side effect. But it seems to me the same utterly evil trap like forgetting () after a function.

Comment: That's why you shouldn't use `<<` but `doLast` do add a task action. The latter also allows you to configure the task at the same time.

Comment: but, if I want to make use of incremental builds, I don't have another choice than << ... right?

Comment: `doLast` will work just as well (and I'm not sure how you draw a connection to incremental builds here).

Comment: well, I only want to clear the property file on gradle clean and only want to write the property on gradle war, preferred only if the file does not exist. this would be an incremental step, right?